# Can I use experimentalDecorators in enterprise projects?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-next

ES decorators have experimental status. Can I use --experimentalDecorators flag for TypeScript in enterprise projects or will ES decorators be change in future?

Answer (score 0):

Well, currently decorators are at [proposal stage 2](https://github.com/tc39/proposals), so they *might* still change. I have no idea how likely a change is exactly, but personally i would estimate it to be rather low, especially since projects like Angular2+ heavily utilize them already all over the place.

Comment: The proposal [already has changed](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators#how-does-this-proposal-compare-to-other-versions-of-decorators).

Comment: @abetteroliver: True, but the people involved are well aware of the wide-spread use decorators see already, also citing instances like TypeScript and Angular. Migration will probably not be very difficult; maybe there will even be a legacy option for TS which keeps the old transpiled functions.